# Run docker commands without sudo & without adding user in group

Tags: linux, docker, centos7

We are having a requirement to run the docker commands without the sudo user or without adding the users to a docker group.

I tried to explore on the rootless docker but it is not getting installed on our centos 7 machine.

ref: https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/rootless/

And we are using NIS for all the other users so, we want to do something due to which all the developers which we have can make use of docker without actually providing them sudo access.

Also, we don't want to add these many users to the docker group.

Our machine configs:

```
# cat /etc/os-release
NAME="CentOS Linux"
VERSION="7 (Core)"
ID="centos"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="7"
PRETTY_NAME="CentOS Linux 7 (Core)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:centos:centos:7"
HOME_URL="https://www.centos.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.centos.org/"

CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT="CentOS-7"
CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT_VERSION="7"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="centos"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="7"
```

Comment: When users can start docker containers, they pretty much have root access on the host machine. https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/#docker-daemon-attack-surface

Comment: Oh! but actually we have everything containerized and this is so much required for the developers in our organization to make use of Docker commands. :(

Answer (score 1):

If this is about locking down access to remote servers, then instead of permitting access to docker via SSH you could enable the :2376 socket for mtls encrypted comms. Now the problem becomes one of certificate distribution which is arguably worse.

As mentioned in the comments, whatever user the dockerd runs as is the effective user that people with access to the docker api are running as, as docker has no attempt at RBAC. If you want that, as much as I like docker and docker swarm, this is one of those points where your requirements really indicate you should be using Kubernetes.